# get status code as output from Apache "access" log file format

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

How do i output the status code using the above code snippet,
I tried using the cut command but there seems to be some problem

Comment: Try `awk '{print $(NF-1)}' access.log`

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output (don't expect us to know what part of that line is the status code) and show your attempt to solve the problem yourself. If the "status code" can show up in different positions (i.e. more space-separated strings before or after it) on different lines then include a few more lines of input/output.

Comment: Btw "there seems to be some problem" is the worst possible problem description. [edit] your question to tell us in what way there's a problem - wrong output, no output, error messages, core dumps, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use awk you can do one of two things:
if you assume the status is always the 9th field (remember it tokenizes using spaces by default)

```
  awk '{print $9}'
```

or if you assume it is always the second to last field (as @anubhave mentioned in comments):

```
  awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

If you prefer sed

```
  sed -n  's/.*GET [^ ]* HTTP[^ ]*" \([0-9]\{3\}\) .*/\1/p'
```